# Directx font through memory

Tags: c++, windows, directx, direct3d, directx-9

I want to be able to make create a ID3DXFont* through a byte array. How can I do this? I've looked around and saw people saying AddFontMemResourceEx but I don't know how to use this to make a font, and I can't find anything on it.

Comment: google is your friend https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/551900-using-fonts-in-directx-from-resource-files/

Comment: so what i use AddFontMemResourceEx with the bytes then call D3DXCreateFont with the name of what the font was before it was loaded in memory? @SimonMourier